# How to disable JUL in 3rd party jar?

Tags: java, logging, java.util.logging

In 3rd party jar logger exist this code. 
'Logger.getLogger("net.java.ao").log(Level.INFO, sql.toString());'
How can I disable this logger from my program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to raise the LogLevel for the given logger-name "net.java.ao".
Therefore, try to specify a custom Logger-configuration using the Java System-Property: "java.util.logging.config.file".

In the file you specified using the above system property, you can simply add the following line:

net.java.ao.level = OFF

Alternatively, you can also use the System-property: "java.util.logging.config.class", as described in the API docs: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogManager.html.

Comment: :(
it is not influence - all of ways

Comment: maybe, because it is 3rd party jar?

Comment: You could try to set a JUL-configuration directly within your Main-Class' static initialization block:

static {
  LogManager lm = LogManager.getLogManager();
  lm.reset();
  String config ="handlers = java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler\n" +
  ".level = OFF\n"+
  "java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = OFF\n" +
  "java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter\n";
  lm.readConfiguration(new ByteArrayInputStream(config.getBytes()));
}